# Beanstalkd tube missing

Tags: beanstalkd, pheanstalk

Integrated Pheanstalk library in my web app. Created three tubes for three type of jobs. 
Created a beanstalkd web console also to see the job status.
All are working fine.

The issue is, today when I checked the console, one of the tubes is missing. I restarted beanstalkd and it appeared and started working again. Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tubes are created on demand whenever they are referenced. If a tube is empty
>   (that is, it contains no ready, delayed, or buried jobs) and no client refers
>   to it, it will be deleted.  -- https://github.com/beanstalkd/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt

The tube will be re-created as soon as a new job is put into it. Normally you would `watch` all of the tube(s) that a particular worker can deal with, and a `reserve` would return the next job from any of the watched tubes based on the specified ordering, or first-come-first-served, as appropriate.